# Windows 10 notifications limited to 4 lines

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

On Windows 10, the length of the text in the notification bubbles seems to be limited to 4 lines, which was not the case in previous Windows versions. This is an issue if you need to use older programs that don't take this limitation into account. Is there a way to remove this limitation?

Comment: *Is there a way to remove this limitation?* - No; The notifications are also not identical by design.

Comment: Isn't that notification feature built-in the UWP app during programming?